# Updating multiple documents using Firestore Transaction

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

**Use case:** I have multiple notes and each one is tied to a label. If the user deletes a label, all the notes associated with that label are tied to the default label. So to make it work, I first need to find out all the notes with that label, replace their label id with default label's id, and finally delete the selected label. All this needs to be atomic and hence the Firestore `Transaction`.

The problem arises because I want to `get()` multiple documents by firing a `query`. Since it is an `async` operation, the whole purpose of the transaction vanishes. The examples I saw in the documentation are about a single document.

```
FirebaseConstants.getRootRef()  // db reference
        .runTransaction((Transaction.Function<Void>) transaction -> {
            FirebaseConstants.getNotesRef()  // Notes collection reference
                    .whereEqualTo("labelDetails.id", "<old_label_id>")
                    .get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(snapshots -> {
                        ArrayList<String> listIds = new ArrayList<>();

                        for (DocumentSnapshot snap : snapshots.getDocuments()) {
                            listIds.add(snap.getId());
                        }

                        for (String id : listIds) {
                            FirebaseConstants.getNotesRef()
                                    .document(id)
                                    .update("labelDetails.id", "<default_label_id>");
                        }

                        // Labels collection reference
                        FirebaseConstants.getLabelsRef().document("<old_label_id>").delete();
                    });
            return null;
        })
        .addOnSuccessListener(snapshots -> {
            Toast.makeText(this, "transaction success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
            Toast.makeText(this, "transaction failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        });
```

So, I would really like to know how to handle this case. I know, I can `get()` the matching ids first and then run the transaction inside `get`'s `OnSuccessListener` (or even a Batch Write, since `get()` is already done), but that doesn't guarantee data consistency between `get()` and my `update()`, does it?

Hence, I am wondering how this should be done. How to `get` and `update` multiple documents using `Transaction`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore does **not** support transactional consistency in clients apps that obtain documents through queries.  Notice that the `transaction` object doesn't have any way to perform a query.  You can only do individual document get() operations.

In order to get an atomic update, you must use the provided [Transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Transaction) object for all document retrievals and updates.  You must first read a document before you can write it (but if you read a document, you don't have to write it).

If you need to work with documents that come from the result of a query, you should perform the query **outside** the transaction and remember the IDs of each document for use in the transaction.  If the results of the query would change before the transaction is complete (for example, a document would be added or removed), then your transaction is going to deal with data that is "out of date".

A transaction only makes sense if you need to read the document's contents in order to make a decision before you write it.  In your case, you are not actually using the contents of each document to decide what to do with it.  In this case, a batch write is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think I am better off with batch writes.

Answer (score 1):

> I can get() the matching ids first and then run the transaction inside get's OnSuccessListener (or even a Batch Write, since get() is already done), but that doesn't guarantee data consistency between get() and my update(), does it?

Yes, a batch write will solve your problem. There is no consistency problem in this case because the batch writes are atomic operations, either all of the operations succeed, or none of them are applied. So you should create the desired query, get all needed documents and add all of them to a batch of update operations. In the end, simply call `commit()`. Be aware that there is a limitation of 500 operations per batch. If you need more than that, you should create your own mechanism to update the documents in chunks of 500 operations.

Comment: What about the time gap between get and update? Here I don't care (that much) because I am directly replacing data, but imagine a case where I have to increment counter of multiple documents or none's.

Comment: To perform such an operation over the network it takes time. Depending on your connection speed and the state, it may take from a few hundred milliseconds, even to a few seconds before such an operation completes. You should always count that amount of time and try to make everything possible to have less time. O solution might also be to host your database in a location that is closest to your users. Regarding the increment **only** of the counter, there is no need for a transaction or a batch, you can simply use `FieldValue.increment(yourNewValue)`.